# AngularJS how to change part of a model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have action links on a page that change parts of the model. The links have ng-click functions that fire a server action that returns the part of the model that was altered. I assign the result of $http.get(...) to the part of the model that was changed. But the data is never resolved.

```
GuideControllers.controller('VideoDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', 'Video',
    function($scope, $http, $routeParams, Video, Preference) {
        $scope.video = Video.get({ id: $routeParams.id });
        $scope.addToWatchlist = function(id) {
            $scope.video.prefs = $http.get('/api/preference/'+id+'/add_to_watchlist.json')
        }
    }
]);
```

The first Video.get(...) fills in the model with a promise that eventually changes the page, the video.prefs are correct when resolved. But when I fetch the video.prefs individually they never get resolved. I tried saving the $http.get promise in a separate variable then on $http.get(...).success(... I copied the parts out the the variable to videos.prefs but that didn't work either since the temp viable was a promise--I guess.

How should I change part of the model by asking the server for just that bit?

Comment: You need a `.success` after the `.get`, or else it wont resolve, unless you're doing that later.

Comment: How are you accessing the `$scope.video.prefs`? Is it a HTML bind?

Comment: tymeJV: I tried assigning the prefs in .success function but that didn't work. The debugger said the prefs were a promise, I couldn't see that there were values there. 

CaioToOn: example ng-class="{iconSelected : video.prefs.user_watchlist == 0}" or in a content tag <div>{{video.prefs.user_watchlist}}</div> The first display on template fetch works fine, after the $http.get the values are blank/null/undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
GuideControllers.controller('VideoDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', 'Video',
    function($scope, $http, $routeParams, Video, Preference) {
        $scope.video = Video.get({ id: $routeParams.id });

        $scope.addToWatchlist = function(id) {
            $http.get('/api/preference/'+id+'/add_to_watchlist.json').success(function(data) {
                $scope.video.prefs = data;
            });
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: Et voila, this is the answer.

Comment: At first I left the `$scope.video.prefs = $http.get(...` in and the UI flashed. This is apparently because for the time until the callback is executed prefs is a promise so its values are undefined, which causes an ng-class in the template to have an invalid expression, causing the css to be removed. This left a bad UI state for any objects referring to prefs. Took out the assignment, only assigned in the callback, and the flash goes away showing a smooth UI transition. BTW ng-cloak does not help with this.